# Generate this expanding series

Tags: code-golf, math

## Challenge

Your task is to generate a string using this sequence:

```
1,1,2,1,1,2,3,2,1,1,3,2,4,2,3,1,....
```

Which is more understandable in this format:

```
1
1 2 1
1 2 3 2 1
1 3 2 4 2 3 1
1 4 3 2 5 2 3 4 1
```

The pattern increases the number of Digits in the string by two for each increment in the Value of N

**For each integer value up to the total N, *aside from 1*** the string is centred on the current value of N and bookended by the previous values of N in decreasing order on the left, and increasing order on the right - with the exception of the value 1, which bookends the entire string.

## Input

Number of steps

## Output

The series separated by comma

Comment: What is the expected output for \$n=3\$? `[1,1,2,1,1,2,3,2,1]`? `[[1],[1,2,1],[1,2,3,2,1]]`? `[1,2,3,2,1]`? Or any of those?

Comment: "Your task is to generate a series like this" implies \$n=3\$ should give `[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1]`. For some reason, people are submitting solutions for the row of the "more understandable in this format".

Comment: I suggest removing the "separated by a comma" text, which appears to override site defaults - most languages will at least wrap a list in some kind of brackets and many will delimit with both space and comma, some may use semi-colons or just spaces. We prefer not to ask answerers to format their output unless it's a core part of the challenge, and as you can see none of the six answers (including mine) have actually followed this instruction.

Comment: I can't understand the way the sequence is generated.

Comment: @JonathanAllan it's unclear at present, so most of us have gone for the option which has the shortest code. I had the `)F` version prepared anyway so have added it to my answer.

Comment: @RGS it seems to be `[1, n -1, n - 2, n - 3, ..., 2, n, 2, ..., n - 3, n - 2, n - 1, 1]` if I've understood it correctly.

Comment: This description: `A middle number is incremented by 1 and being surrounded by its previous number.` in your challenge does not appear accurate with regards to the sequence provided. Additionally, it would be more accurate to say the number of digits in the string increments by 2 as opposed to `Here is a pattern that numbers in each step is increasing by 2`

Comment: Think if Jonathan's ,Nick's and T3RROR's comments were integrated into the challenge we'd be good to go.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I used said that because not for the formatting and just showing the list.

Comment: @T3RR0R then you mean I need to express it matmetically?

Comment: @Noodle9 yes their comments are appropriate please go with them!

Comment: @NickKennedy thanks for the mathmetical expression of the series.

Comment: @RGS please see NickKennedy comment.

Comment: @Arnuald output for n = 3 is [1,1,2,1,1,2,3,2,1]

Comment: @WasifHasan **You** need to edit the challenge incorporating those comments. **Then** I (and I'm sure others) will vote to reopen.

Comment: `The pattern increases the number of Digits` -> `...integers` (e.g when we get to 10). Also still - why a string and why the strict formatting and not just allow any list construct to be output?

Comment: I still don't understand this: "bookended by the previous values of N in decreasing order on the left, and increasing order on the right"

Comment: Similar to [A006968](https://oeis.org/A006968)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

Port of the Jelly answer.

```
L¦ÁR1šû
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f59Cyw41BhkcXHt79/7@hAQA)

## Explanation

```
L       1 .. N
 ¦      Tail
  Á     Shift right
   R    Reverse
    1š  Prepend 1
      û Palindromize
```

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

If the whole format is necessary, here's one with 9 bytes. (Question: Does 05AB1E have any sort of implicit range?)

```
LεL¦ÁR1šû
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f59xWn0PLDjcGGR5deHj3//@GBgA)

Comment: To myself 2 months ago. Yes there is, take a look at the Loops section in the 05AB1E wiki. But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 10 ?8 bytes

```
Ḋṙ-U1;ŒB
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9qZWxsef//4biK4bmZLVUxO8WSQv874oCcIC0@IOKAnTvDh@G5viQKMTDDh@KCrFn/)

I’m assuming you want the \$n\$th row of the pyramid. If you actually want the full sequence for the \$n\$th step, then it would be [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9qZWxsef//4biK4bmZLVUxO8WSQilG/zvigJwgLT4g4oCdO8OH4bm@JAoxMMOH4oKsWf8).

A monadic link taking an integer and returning a list of integers.

### Explanation

```
Ḋ        | List 1..(n-1)
 ṙ-      | Rotate right 1
   U     | Reverse list
    1;   | Prepend 1
      ŒB | Bounce (mirror
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>86</s> <s>81</s> <s>58</s> 53 bytes

```python
lambda n:[[1],[1,*(l:=range(2,n))[::-1],n,*l,1]][n>1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcoxDoMwDADAva/wGEfu4LIgS/QjJkOqNhApmChi4fWhEvNdPY91t2Gsradp7iVun28EE1UOpEzeFZlatOXnXmSIKvL8i5EvxCGovTn0tDfIkA3uyMSM8gCoLdvhfHIZsV8) Hats off to @Noodle9 for saving me a *whooping* 23 bytes and thanks to @squid for saving me 5 bytes!

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcoxDsIwDEDRnVN4jJswmC7IUrmI8RBE00YKbhR14fQhEsOf/qvfcz9svtfW0/LsJX5e7wjGIqRh5F3hRaYWbVvdLRgqCvN1DDH1xQ@iYg/Sno4GGbLB31IgQr4A1JbtdFNyGbH/AA)

Comment: @Noodle9 I was so sure the `f-string` formatting was going to be the way to go... xD

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcoxDoMwDADAva/wGEfu4LIgS/QjJkOqNhApmChi4fWhEvNdPY91t2Gsradp7iVun28EE1UOpEzeFZlatOXnXmSIKvL8i5EvxCGovTn0tDfIkA3uyMSM8gCoLdvhfHIZsV8 "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: @squid nice one, doing the `*l` inside the list to return!

Comment: Far too much later, [another -3](https://tio.run/##JcoxDoMwDADAnVd4tFMzuCyVJfhIyJCqhEZKTRSx8Pow9Oar1/k9bHrV1tO89hJ/708EUy/h4R0WnVu0fcMnG5FXHSWwsSsswaEtQj0dDTJkg38UFiEdAGrLdqJLmIn6DQ "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 182 bytes

Unfortunately this became the longest solution over here...

```erlang
q(I)->lists:join(" ",[integer_to_list(X)||X<-lists:seq(2,I-1)]).
x(0)->"";x(I)->x(I-1)++"\n"++if I>1->"1 "++lists:reverse(q(I))++" "++integer_to_list(I)++" "++q(I)++" 1";1<2->"1"end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BDoMgEEX3noKwglCMuFTjnhuYWGNMOxoaixVI68K7U6jtprOYzOT9@X/AzIOeONiLUQ/nE78SSXk9K@tscVuUJhjhU6u0gwlM75Y@ItLQfW8qfsgsrCQ/SS5oR9NkI1kwwLjcPk6hB8AYPmvMmBqRrEXAAoXtODfwBGOBxOQojOQ/T/7A@h0FLkWVRyMM@pr6@xBebTuKeJ2gUGopxpdRDshGREZp6t8)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>68</s>  65 bytes

Returns the whole sequence after \$n\$ iterations.

```javascript
f=n=>--n?[...f(n),1,...(g=k=>k>1?[k,...g(k-1),k]:[n+1])(n),1]:[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpNCoAgEEDh68yQCrNoE6gHERdRKTUyRkXXt5/d@@Bt4z2e07Hul5Y6L60lK9ZpLT4YYxIIKlJvQbZsHTvygT9nYE2oOA5BOor4jy8otqnKWctiSs2QoEdsDw)

---

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>53</s>  46 bytes

Returns the \$n\$<sup>th</sup> row of the pyramid.

```javascript
n=>(g=k=>k>1?[k%n||1,...g(k-1),k%n||1]:[n])(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcqxCoMwEIDh3ae4pXCHMZDBxfbig4iDqAk2cle0uNQ@eyp0@uHjfw7HsI/b8npXotOcA2dhj5ET@@Rd26WbnKcz1tqIqXJk/tA3nfSEQjnohgIM7g4CD4b6alkSfAqAUWXXdbarRhQD4fqp@OYf)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 145 bytes

```cs
n=>{var s= "";for(int i=0;i++<n;){for(int j=1;++j<=i;)s+=(j>2?i-j+2:1)+",";s+=i;for(int j=i;j-->1;)s+=","+(j>1?i-j+1:j);s+=i<n?",":"";}return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY4xC8MgEIX3/IrDSbkKNdAlp2br1L1zCUk5BwtquoT8diuBtm9873v3bsp6ylyva5wsx3KCXBLHp4fF1ej89n4kyA6EoOWVZCOA3ZkY0UZS29cLzhBisI5JZXQy@H5kHbAfjEJxEtRMpj/NFLT25oBbjK1gjoIZgjpgG8cWDG13T3NZU4RMe6Wu3YDfG4DIYB1cCFQHTffEZb5xnOUiWSmqHw)

Function generating whole series.

Comment: [135 bytes](https://tio.run/##Nc2xCsMgEIDhPU9xOClGqIEuOTVbp@6dS0jKOVhQ0yXk2e010Fv/7@7mYuZC7bal2VGqPZSaKb0CrL4lH/bPM0PxIASu7yxZAPlLH5G0dgmL9uTSJHoxCqH2H4neYuRIqLjKGIaJTNTDaJVmd57hED1hNCbYk3HQTO1J7RgVHnmpW05Q8GjY8RL8nyNoTeA8XBFUBzyPTHW5U1rkKkkpbF8 "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

(9 if we only require the \$n^{\text{th}}\$ row of the "understandable format" - remove `)F`)

```
,2œṖRUFŒB)F
```

A monadic link accepting an integer, the number of steps, which yields a list of integers, the series up to and including that step.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/H6OjkhzunBYW6HZ3kpOn2//9/UwA)**